# Generating a completly random base64 encoded image in PHP?

Tags: php, image

I need to quickly generate an image (base64 encoded JPEG) to simulate an API call.

Of course I can:

```
public function readImageApiCall($imageId)
{
    return function () use ($imageid) {
        return ['result' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('myimage.jpg'))];
    }
}
```

But I don't care the actual image content, i just need a valid JPEG image without the need of placing a dummy image in the filesystem.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no plural then...

Comment: why are you over-complicating it? you just need a *single* image in the FS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with gd PHP extension and imagejpeg (you must capture output buffer)

A sample to how to create an image from scrach

http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml

a link to PHP manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

But, why you don't set it in the code?

```
$result = "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";
```